# replacing x[i by x[i] in R for i =1,2,3,4

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to replace Gene1, Gene2, Gene3 and Gene4 by x[1], x[2], x[3] and x[4]. I was able to get one sided bracket but do not know how to add the other one.

######code

```
install.packages("BoolNet")
library(BoolNet)
    n<-generateRandomNKNetwork(4,3,readableFunctions="canonical")
    n$interactions$Gene1$expression

func=list() 
gfunc=list()

for (i in 1:4){ 
  func[[i]]<-noquote(n$interactions[[paste0("Gene",i)]]$expression)
      gfunc[[i]]<-gsub("Gene", "x[", func[[i]])

}
##########################
############output###########
func

 [[1]]
[1] (!Gene1 & Gene4 & !Gene3) | (!Gene1 & Gene4 & Gene3) | (Gene1 & !Gene4 &       !Gene3) | (Gene1 & Gene4 & Gene3)

[[2]]
[1] (!Gene2 & !Gene3 & !Gene4) | (!Gene2 & !Gene3 & Gene4) | (!Gene2 & Gene3  & !Gene4)

[[3]]
[1] (!Gene2 & !Gene3 & !Gene1) | (!Gene2 & Gene3 & !Gene1) | (!Gene2 & Gene3     & Gene1) | (Gene2 & Gene3 & !Gene1) | (Gene2 & Gene3 & Gene1)

[[4]]
[1] (!Gene3 & Gene2 & !Gene4) | (!Gene3 & Gene2 & Gene4) | (Gene3 & !Gene2 & !Gene4) | (Gene3 & Gene2 & Gene4)

gfunc
[[1]]
[1] (!x[1 & x[4 & !x[3) | (!x[1 & x[4 & x[3) | (x[1 & !x[4 & !x[3) | (x[1 &  x[4 & x[3)

[[2]]
[1] (!x[2 & !x[3 & !x[4) | (!x[2 & !x[3 & x[4) | (!x[2 & x[3 & !x[4)

[[3]]
[1] (!x[2 & !x[3 & !x[1) | (!x[2 & x[3 & !x[1) | (!x[2 & x[3 & x[1) | (x[2 & x[3 & !x[1) | (x[2 & x[3 & x[1)

[[4]]
[1] (!x[3 & x[2 & !x[4) | (!x[3 & x[2 & x[4) | (x[3 & !x[2 & !x[4) | (x[3 &  x[2 & x[4)
```

Comment: Are you expecting there to be evaluation of those strings with retrieval of values from some object named "x"? If so, then you should instead describe what you want to do because this workflow seems inappropriate for the R language.

Comment: Yes. I want to evaluate those boolean expressions at a randomly generated starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is requested, although I admit I'm not sure what the purpose is:

```
 for (i in 1:4){ 
   func[[i]]<-noquote(n$interactions[[paste0("Gene",i)]]$expression)
       gfunc[[i]]<-gsub("(Gene)([[:digit:]])", "x[\\2]", func[[i]])
               }

> gfunc
[[1]]
[1] (!x[1] & x[2] & !x[4]) | (x[1] & !x[2] & x[4]) | (x[1] & x[2] & !x[4])

[[2]]
[1] (!x[4] & !x[2] & !x[1]) | (!x[4] & !x[2] & x[1]) | (x[4] & !x[2] & x[1])

[[3]]
[1] (!x[2] & !x[3] & x[4]) | (!x[2] & x[3] & !x[4]) | (x[2] & !x[3] & !x[4]) | (x[2] & !x[3] & x[4])

[[4]]
[1] (!x[2] & !x[3] & x[1]) | (!x[2] & x[3] & x[1]) | (x[2] & x[3] & !x[1])
```

Comment: I want to evaluate those boolean expressions at a randomly generated starting point. For example :g1=function(x){(!x[3]&x[4])}
 then g1(c(0,1,0,1))
[1] TRUE

Comment: Did I fail to deliver what was requested?

Comment: The reason I asked is that you neither upvoted nor checkmarked the answer. So until you do so it will remain in the Unanswered Questions queue and people looking for R questions to work on will continue to see it.